# Print array php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I got this array output in php:

```
Array
(
    [blabla0] => Array
        (
            [0] => lalala
            [1] => lelele
        )

    [blabla1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lalala
            [1] => lelele
        )

)
```

If I'd like to print by associative name, it's like this: `$myArray['blabla0'][0]` , and it works. But I want to do like this: `echo $myArray[0][0]`, by index...is there any way?

Comment: maybe with a foreach loop

Comment: `echo $myArray[array_keys($myArray)[0]][0];`.... requires PHP >= 5.4 for the array dereferencing

Comment: @MarkBaker that same thing can be lengthened a bit to support older versions, as such: `$arr_keys=array_keys($myArray); echo $myArray[$arr_keys[0]][0]`, and OP you can do that with for/foreach loops as well

Answer (score 1):

Mark bakers answer is best for one option. You can convert all of the array with `array_values` eg

```
$new_array = array_values($old_array);
echo $new_array[0][0];
```

It depends how many times you wish to access the array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Thanks everyone, you help me so much! I could do it converting, and I think it'll work for me this way.